# How to minimize install of Qt for using PyQt on MacOS?

Tags: macos, qt, pyqt, qmake, qt5.4

I was trying to install PyQt on my MacOS. With SIP installed, an error occurred when `python3 PyQt-gpl-5.4/configure.py` inputted:

`Error: Use the --qmake argument to explicitly specify a working Qt qmake.`

It seems that Qt should be installed before PyQt. There're many optional components in the installation of Qt:

-Qt 5.4

--clang 64-bit

--source components

---Add-Ons

---Essentials

--.....

Which components should I choose for installing qmake??

Answer (score 0):

`qmake` is the executable that is included with any version of the qt libraries; and there is a different version of `qmake` for each compiler the Qt Libraries are built with/against.  On a mac, and for building projects that run on OSX, you will probably want `clang x64`.  And you will find qmake under `~/Qt/5.x/clang_64/bin`  It will also install qt creator (I don't think you can uncheck it), but you don't need all the extras besides that.

Building with qmake often needs XCode installed and the Command Line Tools (CLT) to use its included compiler.  With Python, you probably won't need the compiler, unless you need to build some of its libraries.

Hope that helps.